# Importing a class into another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, tkinter

as I'm still learning python I came up to a problem.

Why does this work:

```
class SomeOtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 10
        print(self.number)

    def increase(self):
        self.number += 1
        print(self.number)

class MyMainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.otherClass = MyClass()

app = MyMainClass() #Output: 10
app.otherclass.increase() #Output: 11
```

but this doesn't:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyMainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tkinter() # <-- Error: see below.

app = MyMainClass()
app.tk.title("My window")
...
```

Both times I include a class, but in the second example it says:

> NameError: global name 'Tkinter' is not defined

Where's the difference between those examples and how can I solve this, so I'm able to use tkinter in my class?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `What's the difference between those examples` What's the similarity? The first example doesn't even using Tkinter. Did you mean to do `self.tk = Tk()`?

Comment: Your problem is that there is nothing called `Tkinter` in that module. I would strongly suggest you do a tutorial on object-oriented programming in Python - like [this](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) one.

Comment: Like I already wrote: I think both times I try to use a class in another class, but one time it works, the other time it doesn't.

Comment: @EverydayLearning: Because there's no class called `Tkinter`. The fact that it's in another class has nothing to do with it (for instance, try putting the line `tk = Tk()` outside the class). Where did you get the line `self.tk = Tkinter()`?

Comment: I made this line by myself, but I don't know why I did it this way. I used Tkinter often before this, but didn't see this error. Thanks.

Comment: Actually your last comment is a brilliant example of why the star import is really bad—looks like you're not even an (absolute) beginner but still got tricked by this.

Comment: Help a beginner, don't downvote cause the question was way too easy to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you meant `Tk()`? the `tkinter` module on Python 3.x does not seem to contain a class `Tkinter`.

As to the meaning of your question and example... well, the examples are absolutely irrelevant, and the question should simply be "why can't I create an instance of `Tkinter`" or something.

**Python Lesson:** This is also a good example of why it's a bad idea to use star imports (i.e `from <module> import *`, because `*` looks like a star). This imports everything from `tkinter`, but doesn't let you know if something you thought was there actually isn't

```
from tkinter import *
```

whereas this

```
from tkinter import Tkinter
```

would have immediately pointed out that (the class) `Tkinter` does not exist in `tkinter`. Another option that some seem to prefer (incl. myself in some cases), is `import tkinter` followed by `tkinter.Tk()`, which has the advantage that it's obvious where a class comes from. Futhermore, [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) also discourages the use of star imports (referring to them as "wildcard imports").

Comment: Wow, thank you. I almost spent the whole last day to find a solutions, and this was my problem.. I could beat myself :x

Comment: You know... *"wow, thank you"* directly translates to StackOverflow'ese as *"Accept"* ;)

Comment: Although in the specific case of tkinter, I think star import is less frowned upon than with other modules.

Comment: It's typical of the documentation of various libraries to start out by guiding you to use `from <libraryx> import *`, but it doesn't make it any less frowned upon—because the reasons why it's bad are still there, as you've just demonstrated. In other words, there is *generally* no reason why something would be less frowned upon just because it's using a library.

Comment: I presumed it was because you usually need to use a large amount of Tkinter, and the names are relatively unlikely to clash, unlike for instance with the random module, where something like you just needing the random function, and then importing shuffle as well and having a name conflict there would be more likely.

Comment: If the amount is large, `tkinter.Tkinter()` is a good alternative.

Comment: `import tkinter as tk`. Then at least you don't have to type all of `tkinter` before everything.